# Restrict jQueryUI drag to element, but allow moving from element to element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two squares (divs) side by side. When you drag an item around inside of one I want it restricted to that one, but, if you move your mouse cursor out of it and into the next square over, I want the element to pop out of the first square and into the second and be restricted to the second (and then vice-versa if you move mouse back into the first again while still dragging). But, at no time should the element overlap the squares (it should be wholly always inside of either one or the other). How can I do this? I'm using jQuery UI.

http://jsbin.com/gecucotu/1/edit?js,output

Comment: From a UI/UX perspective I'm not sure I'd implement it that way. If a user is manipulating something visually, it should be as responsive as possible at all times. Instead, I would suggest allowing the items to be dragged across the container boundaries, but as soon as the mouse is released, move them into the one they're closer to. I have a feeling that will feel more natural.

Comment: I don't disagree with your assessment, but, I have to do it this way if for no other reason than to show my pointy haired boss how not-good it feels. Then off to usability/user testing with this version lined up against what you suggested. Then based on actual user research we decide which way "wins".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't get jQuery UI to do it, but, was able to do it using Vanilla JavaScript

http://jsfiddle.net/cmcculloh/676fr/

```
var dragging = false;
var lastE;

$('#t1').mousedown(function(e){
    dragging = true;
});

$('body').mousemove(function(e){
    lastE = e;  
}).mouseup(function(e){
    dragging = false;
});


var placeT = function placeT(e) {
    var newX = Math.round((e.pageX - 2)/20) * 20;
    var newY = Math.round((e.pageY - 2)/20) * 20;

    if(newX <= 100){
         $('#t1').offset({ left: newX });
    }else if(newX >= 220 && newX <= 300){
         $('#t1').offset({ left: newX });
    }else{

    }
     $('#t1').offset({ top: newY });
}

var drag = function drag() {
    if(dragging){
        placeT(lastE);
    }
    window.setTimeout(drag, 1);    

};
window.setTimeout(drag, 100);
```

Comment: That is stellar! Wish I could upvote it again. Very well done buddy. :)